# Synchronizing nested Maps and Sets (Java)

Tags: java, dictionary, synchronization, nested, set

I have a nested set within a map within a map that I am trying to synchronize over two threads.

The map is instantiated as such:

```
private final Map<Manageable, Map<String, Set<Manageable>>> manageableMap = 
        Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Manageable, Map<String, Set<Manageable>>>());
```

This is the function I use to add values to the map:

```
private void put(Manageable key, Manageable value, String valueType) {
    synchronized (manageableMap) {
        Map<String, Set<Manageable>> setMap = manageableMap.get(key);
        if (setMap == null) {
            setMap = new HashMap<String, Set<Manageable>>();
            manageableMap.put(key, Collections.synchronizedMap(setMap));
        }

        synchronized (setMap) {
            Set<Manageable> set = setMap.get(valueType);
            if (set == null) {
                set = new HashSet<Manageable>();
                setMap.put(valueType, Collections.synchronizedSet(set));
            }

            synchronized (set) {
                set.add(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Intellij IDEA warns me that I am synchronizing on local variables setMap and set.

I am fairly new to synchronization and I was wondering if this is the proper way to 
synchronize a nested data structure like this.

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to synchronize on manageableMap. Only 1 thread at a time can acquire the lock on manageableMap, so if a thread has acquired the lock on manageableMap, further locking on set and setMap is not needed, since only 1 thread (the thread that locked manageableMap) can access set and setMap.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am still getting used to this synchronizing thing. What other times do I need to use a synchronized block?

Comment: It is a complicated subject.  This is an excellent book if you are looking to learn more, http://www.amazon.com/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601

Answer (score 1):

synchronization works on particular object instances, not on the fields or variables holding references to them, so you must make sure that the sunchronization occurs on the same object instances, no matter whether they are refenced  by local variables only.

In that particular case IDEA cannot statically check whether the code does what you want, the warning is just some kind of 'code smell' warning you that the effect might not be as expected.

Best bet is you test your code by logging out the instances that you are synchronizing on and check whether they are the ones you expect - IDEA has also the Option to mark object instances during debugging to check whether the objects you synchronize on are the same or different instances.

Answer (score 1):

If you always control the synchronization manually you probably don't need to use Collections.synchronizedMap. One section synchronized on the target map will do.

Comment: Which way is better or should I say more efficient: Collections.synchronizedMap or Synchronized blocks?

Comment: synchronizedMap contains synchronized(this) in all operations that delegate to the wrapped map. If this method is the only place where you add elements to the map then you don't need to use synchronizedMap, just a regular map. As for performance I would guess version with plain map would be negligibly more efficient - depends on the usage pattern.